# Control.Dropdown doesn’t work

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form with a combo box cboListPeople. The GotFocus event is cboListPeople.Dropdown.  For a fraction of a second I think I can see the dropdown but it immediately closes. Focus remains with cboListPeople and when clicked, the dropdown appears as expected. I have tried loading the form at another control thus:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Me.Role.LimitToList = True
DoCmd.GoToControl “OfficerLookup”
cboListPeople.SetFocus

End Sub
```

The result is the same problem as initially outlined above.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell what's going on from what you've described, but if you're seeing it momentarily, it sounds like you might have a conflict in your code somewhere.  Do you have any macros or expression builder events in place?  If so, there's a possibility of conflicting between these events and your VBA code.

Comment: Thanks. I don't use macros, just vba. I'll do some wider exploration of what's going on.